# SilverStripe 3 GridFieldEditableColumns DateField Calendar

Tags: datepicker, silverstripe

In a `GridField` I use `GridFieldEditableColumns`. The inline editing is working and displays the Calendar when using a `DateTimeField`.

But this is not working when using a `DateField`. (Calendar not showing up). Is there something I am missing?

```
$holiDayConfig = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
$holiDayConfig->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldDataColumns');
$holiDayConfig->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');
$holiDayConfig->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldDetailForm');
$holiDayConfig->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldEditButton');
$holiDayConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldEditableColumns());
$holiDayConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldLayoutHelper());
$holiDayConfig->addComponent($newButton = new GridFieldAddNewInlineButton());
$newButton->setTitle(_t('OpenTimes.AddSchedule', 'add newSchedule'));

$holiDayGridfield = new GridField(_t('OpenTimes.SchedulesTab','Schedules / Holidays'), _t('OpenTimes.ScheduleTab','Schedule / Holidays'), $this->owner->HoliDays(), $holiDayConfig);

$holiDayConfig->getComponentByType('GridFieldEditableColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(
    'Schedule' => array(
        'callback' => function ($record, $column, $holiDayGridfield){

            $tPF = DateField::create('Schedule', 'AM');                 // NOT WORKING 
            $tPF->setConfig('showcalendar', true);                      // NOT WORKING / NO CALENDAR

            //$tPF = DateTimeField::create('Schedule', 'AM');           // WORKING
            //$tPF->getDateField()->setConfig('showcalendar', true);    // WORKING / SHOWING CALENDAR

            return $tPF;
        },
        'title' => _t('OpenTimes.On', 'On')
    )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the SilverStripe JavaScript targets an `input` field inside a `div` with the classnames `.field` and `.date`. A normal `DateField` in the CMS will have this parent `div`. A `DateField` inside the `GridFieldEditableColumn` does not have this parent `div`.

Here is the current JavaScript that applies the date picker calendar:

**framework/admin/javascript/LeftAndMain.js**

```
$('.cms .field.date input.text').entwine({
    onmatch: function() {
        var holder = $(this).parents('.field.date:first'), config = holder.data();
        if(!config.showcalendar) {
            this._super();
            return;
        }

        config.showOn = 'button';
        if(config.locale && $.datepicker.regional[config.locale]) {
            config = $.extend(config, $.datepicker.regional[config.locale], {});
        }

        $(this).datepicker(config);
        // // Unfortunately jQuery UI only allows configuration of icon images, not sprites
        // this.next('button').button('option', 'icons', {primary : 'ui-icon-calendar'});

        this._super();
    },
    onunmatch: function() {
        this._super();
    }
});
```

The following file also adds the datepicker for some instances of the `DateField`:

**framework/admin/javascript/DateField.js**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.extend({
        ssDatepicker: function(opts) {
            return $(this).each(function() {
                if($(this).data('datepicker')) return; // already applied

                $(this).siblings("button").addClass("ui-icon ui-icon-calendar");

                var holder = $(this).parents('.field.date:first'),
                    config = $.extend(opts || {}, $(this).data(), $(this).data('jqueryuiconfig'), {});
                if(!config.showcalendar) return;

                if(config.locale && $.datepicker.regional[config.locale]) {
                    config = $.extend(config, $.datepicker.regional[config.locale], {});
                }

                if(config.min) config.minDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', config.min);
                if(config.max) config.maxDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', config.max);

                // Initialize and open a datepicker
                // live() doesn't have "onmatch", and jQuery.entwine is a bit too heavyweight for this, so we need to do this onclick.
                config.dateFormat = config.jquerydateformat;
                $(this).datepicker(config);
            });
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".field.date input.text,.fieldholder-small input.text.date", function() {
        $(this).ssDatepicker();

        if($(this).data('datepicker')) {
            $(this).datepicker('show');
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

The reason this does work for `DateTimeField` is `DateTimeField` still wraps the date input in `div` with the classes `.field` and `.date`, even in the `GridFieldEditableColumn`. I would guess this is because this field has multiple inputs.

The reason this does not work for `DateField` is `GridFieldEditableColumn` does not wrap the input field with this `div`.

To fix this we can add some JavaScript to call the date picker script on our field.

In a config yml file we add a JavaScript file to be loaded by the `LeftAndMain` class:

**mysite/_config/config.yml**

```
---
Name: mysite
After: 'framework/*','cms/*'
---

LeftAndMain:
  extra_requirements_javascript:
    - 'mysite/javascript/cms.js'
```

In our JavaScript file we call `ssDatepicker` on click of our date field.

**mysite/javascript/cms.js**

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', '.cms .ss-gridfield-editable td > input.text.date', function() {
        $(this).ssDatepicker();

        if($(this).data('datepicker')) {
            $(this).datepicker('show');
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I'm sure there is a neat custom JavaScript way to do this. I don't have any free time over the next 2 days, but after that when I get a chance I'll look into it and share what I come up.

Comment: I have added a short simple solution to add the date picker to a `DateField` in an editable grid field column.

Comment: Hi 3dgoo! This is better working now with your solution; Is there a possibility to tell the date picker displaying the right language? (it falls back to 'en' now) Do i have to require_javascript and (require_css) to let the date picker find the region and render properly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: From my testing the date picker automatically uses the language that the current user is set to. I have set my language to German in the CMS user settings and the date picker displays everything in German.

Comment: In my case, its the only DateField in SiteConfig. When using a DatetimeField, jquery-ui.js and jquery.ui.datepicker-de.js (and other?) are loaded. Using the DateField as worked out now, those files are missing.

Comment: In the end i extended DateTimeField and removed all TimeField - parts.

Comment: I have tested having a `DateField` in a `GridField` using `GridFieldEditableColumn` in the `SiteConfig` with the above `cms.js` and the date picker works correctly. There are no missing JavaScript files for me.

Comment: Hi 3dgoo! Thats strange. I'll set up a clean install on a new environment to see what could be a different. I will be back a little later. Thanks. Sepp.

Comment: After further testing: The $localeFile = THIRDPARTY_DIR . "/jquery-ui/datepicker/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-{$lang}.js"; **is loading**. But the only way after a login to the CMS is to navigate from root (http://yoursite/admin) to (in this case) Config. If there is a backurl defined when logging in, the language - file is **not** included. I do a lot of /dev/bulid 's and ?flush=all. Thats the problem.

Comment: Config should be Settings

Answer (score 0):

With the friendly help from @3dgoo i came up with the following:
(to display the datepicker see @3dgoo's answer, last javascript part).
To always have the right language-file included (if exists) i did:

use GridDateField::create('Start', 'On'); instead of DateField::create('Start', 'On')

and class GridDateField extends DateField:

```
<?php
class GridDateField extends DateField {


public function Field($properties = array()) {

    if($this->getConfig('showcalendar')){
        $locale = i18n::get_locale();
        $lang = i18n::get_lang_from_locale($locale);
        $localeFile = THIRDPARTY_DIR . "/jquery-ui/datepicker/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-{$lang}.js";
        if (file_exists(Director::baseFolder() . '/' .$localeFile)){
            Requirements::javascript($localeFile);
        }
    }

     return parent::Field($properties);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the information @3dgoo

The way I implemented it is by creating a custom (form field) template and then assigning it to the DateField, so I didn't need to have any extra JavaScript or extend the class itself:

```
$displayFields['StartDate'] = function($record, $column, $grid) {
    return DateField::create($column)
        ->setConfig('dateformat', 'dd-MM-yyyy')
        ->setConfig('showcalendar', true)
        ->setTemplate('GridFieldEditable_DateField');
};
```

The field template just wraps the input in a div having the field and date classes

`<div class="field date"><input $AttributesHTML /></div>`

Please see the full snippet here:
https://gist.github.com/giovdk21/5001061e0262b7903ca339cc55991870